# Why does my batch create more chunks with more records?

Tags: apex, batch

I have a batch that creates a record depends on the condition.

```
String query = 'SELECT Id, Location_Number__c, Brand_Code__c, ShippingPostalCode, Inn_Code__c, Brand_Group_Code__c, Soft_Goods_Actual_Complete_4__c, Soft_Goods_Actual_Complete_3__c, Soft_Goods_Actual_Complete_2__c, Soft_Goods_Actual_Complete_1__c,  Soft_Goods_Due_4__c, Soft_Goods_Due_3__c, Soft_Goods_Due_2__c, Soft_Goods_Due_1__c, Proposed_License_Term__c, ShippingCity, ShippingState, ShippingStreet, ShippingCountry, Hotel_Status__c, Current_Brand__c, Growth_Room_Count__c, Major_Account__c, Phone, Previous_Brand__c, Name FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name = \'Hotel\' AND License_Expiration_Date__c!=null AND Brand_Code__c!=null AND Soft_Goods_Due_1__c!=null'

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

}
```

When limiting the query to 200, it creates a 1 job process but when I didn't limit it, it creates 6 job processes. Is this the nature for batch?

Does the batch per job process checks again the query from the start or the list or not?

Comment: Just fyi you do not need to use string queries. It would be much easier to read actually if you did a static query. That's when you just put the SOQL directly within square brackets (`[SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...]`). Then you can use multiple lines, don't need to escape your strings, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is the nature of Batch. Batch chunk size vary from 1 to 2000(number of records which can process in single transaction).

By default it process records in size of 200.

From the `Apex Developer Guide` ([Using Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)):

> Each execution of a batch Apex job is considered a discrete
>   transaction. For example, a batch Apex job that contains 1,000 records
>   and is executed without the optional scope parameter from
>   Database.executeBatch is considered five transactions of 200 records
>   each.
>
> An optional parameter scope. This parameter specifies the number of
>   records to pass into the execute method. Use this parameter when you
>   have many operations for each record being passed in and are running
>   into governor limits. By limiting the number of records, you are
>   limiting the operations per transaction. This value must be greater
>   than zero. If the start method of the batch class returns a
>   QueryLocator, the optional scope parameter of Database.executeBatch
>   can have a maximum value of 2,000. If set to a higher value,
>   Salesforce chunks the records returned by the QueryLocator into
>   smaller batches of up to 2,000 records. If the start method of the
>   batch class returns an iterable, the scope parameter value has no
>   upper limit. However, if you use a high number, you can run into other
>   limits.