# AsyncApexJob returning two records for one executed instance of batch

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch, asynchronous, asyncapexjob

When I am executing one batch then that batch runs only once. I have verified it from the 'Apex Jobs' from Setup. But when I am querying the AsyncApexJob for that batch class, it is returning two records created at the same time.

I am running the following query -

```
SELECT Status, ExtendedStatus, format(CreatedDate) FROM AsyncApexJob 
  WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY and ApexClass.Name = 'MyBatchClass' 
  ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

This query return the following result - [image]

But when I look at the Apex Jobs, it shows only one instance of one time[image]

I am unable to figure out the issue here, Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: add `JobType` to your first query (for that matter, add all fields in `AsyncApexJob` to your first query to gain insight

Comment: Thank you! JobType of another record is "BatchApexWorker" with the ParentJobId as the first job's ID whose JobType is "BatchApex".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to gain insight is to add additional fields to your query on AsyncApexJob. These fields are available in the [Object Reference for this object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm?q=asyncapexjob)

```
SELECT Id, JobType, ParentJob.Name, ExtendedStatus 
  FROM AsyncApexJob ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

Most likely, you have jobs of JobType `BatchApexWorker` that point at Jobs of type `BatchApex`

The doc states:

> For batch Apex jobs that run using chunking implementation, multiple child jobs of type BatchApexWorker are created.
> Each of these child job records contains the job Id of the parent Apex job that started their execution. For batch Apex jobs that run using a non-chunking implementation, child jobs aren’t created.

[This answer discusses batch apex chunking](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187563/why-does-my-batch-create-more-chunks-with-more-records)